# Out Of Memory Exception In Get-ChildItem Command PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am using below command to run scan on different remote computers and append the output into .txt file. Command run successfully for some extension but it does not work for some extensions(Due to out of memory exception on PowerShell). When I manually run the command on PowerShell it throws out of memory error. So when I run the script it shows empty file. It only works for those extension which does not throw out of memory error.

```
Get-Childitem -Path $localcommandTwoPath -Include $localcommandTwoExtension -Recurse | Out-File $outputFileNameWithDirectory -Encoding utf8 -Append 


$localComandTwoPath= directory or drive e.g. C:/
$localcommandTwoExtension= extensions e.g. .txt, .0
$outputFileNameWithDirectory= output file path
```

How can I avoid this exception and run the above script for all the extensions.

Comment: It's not clear if it's the local host or the remote host throwing the exception. It would be nice to see what is `$localcommandTwoExtension` holding at the moment of this error too.

Comment: i manually login to remote server through powershell after getting session through powershell when I run command of get child item then it throws out of memory exception for some extensions.

Comment: What properties of `Get-ChildItem` do you want to ouput to the file? You can try getting all directories first and then looping through directories and looping through extensions using `-File` and `-Filter` instead of `-Include`, I think that might consume less memory tho it will take more time.

Comment: if all you want is the list of file names with full paths ... use `robocopy` with the list-only & log options.

Comment: Yes i only want file name with path.

Comment: Did you try using `| Select-Object Name, FullName | Out-File...` ? that might consume less memory.

Comment: No removed -include in my script and added -filter that is working fine now